# Enter data in EditText without default keyboard

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-edittext

How to enter data in my EditText using my own buttons  instead of default keyboard (I mean like in calculator apps). Please write me some method or show suitable example. Thanks.
I initialize veriable, even tried to make some algorithm. But there is no reason to go further without knowing how to input data.
And of course I was looking for the answer.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,bPlus,bMin,bDiv,bMult,bEqual;
String sN1,sN2,func,result;
EditText etEnter;
SoundPool pool; int shot = 0;
TextView tvShow;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calculator);
    initVars();

}
private void initVars(){
    etEnter =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCalc);
    tvShow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShow);
     b0 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button0);
     b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
     b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
     b4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
     b5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
     b6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butt6);
     b7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butt7);
     b8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butt8);
     b9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butt9);
    bMin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bMinus); 
    bPlus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bPlus);
    bDiv = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bDiv);
    bMult = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bMult);
    bEqual = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bEqual);
    b0.setOnClickListener(this);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);
    b4.setOnClickListener(this);
    b5.setOnClickListener(this);
    b6.setOnClickListener(this);
    b7.setOnClickListener(this);
    b8.setOnClickListener(this);
    b9.setOnClickListener(this);
    bMin.setOnClickListener(this);
    bPlus.setOnClickListener(this);
    bDiv.setOnClickListener(this);
    bMult.setOnClickListener(this);
    bEqual.setOnClickListener(this);

    pool = new SoundPool(5,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
    shot = pool.load(this, R.raw.shot, 1);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.button0:

        break;
    case R.id.button1:


        break;
    case R.id.button2:


break;
    case R.id.button3:

break;
    case R.id.button4:

        break;
    case R.id.button5:

break;
    case R.id.butt6:

        break;
    case R.id.butt7:

break;
    case R.id.butt8:

break;
    case R.id.butt9:

break;
    case R.id.bMinus:

func = "-";
break;
        case R.id.bPlus:

func = "+";
break;
        case R.id.bDiv:

func = "/";
break;
        case R.id.bMult:

            func = "*";
            break;
        case R.id.bEqual:
pool.play(shot, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
if(func.contentEquals("+")){
    if(sN1!=null && sN2!=null){
    long l1 = Long.parseLong(sN1);
    long l2 = Long.parseLong(sN2);
    long lRes = l1+l2;
    result = String.valueOf(lRes);
    tvShow.setText(result);
    }else if(sN1!=null && sN2==null){
        tvShow.setText(sN1);
    }
    sN1=sN2=null;
}else if(func.contentEquals("-")){
    if(sN1!=null && sN2!=null){
        long l1 = Long.parseLong(sN1);
        long l2 = Long.parseLong(sN2);
        long lRes = l1-l2;
        result = String.valueOf(lRes);
        tvShow.setText(result);
        }else if(sN1!=null && sN2==null){
            tvShow.setText(sN1);
        }
        sN1=sN2=null;
}else if(func.contentEquals("/")){
    if(sN1!=null && sN2!=null){
        long l1 = Long.parseLong(sN1);
        long l2 = Long.parseLong(sN2);
        long lRes = l1/l2;
        result = String.valueOf(lRes);
        tvShow.setText(result);
        }else if(sN1!=null && sN2==null){
            tvShow.setText(sN1);
        }
        sN1=sN2=null;
}else if(func.contentEquals("*")){
    if(sN1!=null && sN2!=null){
        long l1 = Long.parseLong(sN1);
        long l2 = Long.parseLong(sN2);
        long lRes = l1*l2;
        result = String.valueOf(lRes);
        tvShow.setText(result);
        }else if(sN1!=null && sN2==null){
            tvShow.setText(sN1);
        }
        sN1=sN2=null;
}

break;
}
}
```

and XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/rainbow"
 >


<LinearLayout android:paddingTop="22dp" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etCalc"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:inputType="number" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:paddingRight="33dp" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvShow"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:text=":-)"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/rect_buttons"
    android:gravity="right"
    ></TextView>"
</LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"      android:gravity="center" android:paddingTop="20dp" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bPlus"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="+" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bMinus"
   android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:text="-" />
 <Button
    android:layout_gravity="center"        
    android:id="@+id/bEqual"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:text="=" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:gravity="center" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="2"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="3"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:gravity="center" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="4"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="5"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/butt6"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="6"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:gravity="center" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butt7"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="7"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/butt8"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="8"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/butt9"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="9"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:gravity="center" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bDiv"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:text="/" />
<Button
    android:layout_gravity="center"        
    android:id="@+id/button0"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:text="0" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bMult"  android:layout_width="70dp"   android:layout_height="50dp" android:textSize="30dp" android:text="*" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?&q=android%20create%20custom%20keyboard

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to SO! As a friendly piece of advice - we are not a "gief codez" community. We will gladly help you with any specific issue you have in the code that you have tried yourself. So, what have you tried yourself?

Comment: Thanks for advice. Ectually I have a code, I thought it is not suitable for the question. I'll Public code in a minute.

Comment: "google.com/webhp?&q=android%20create%20custom%20keyboard" gee, 'custom keyboard'..the problem was in formulation. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make your `editText` non focusable/editable and modify the text inside when you click on your buttons. Easy !